# Clojure depth first search maze problem from Classic CS Problems in Python Book

Tags: python, clojure, depth-first-search

I am an experienced self-taught professional Python programmer working my way through the book *Classic Computer Science Problems in Python* to try to catch myself up on some of the things I missed by not going to school for this. I am also currently trying to learn Clojure, and I thought why not kill two birds with one stone by using this book to practice writing Clojure as well. So, I'm using Python as a reference in order to port solutions to Clojure. I have never professionally written code with a lisp or functional programming language. I am new to the Clojure and JVM ecosystems. For all these reasons I feel I would greatly benefit from submitting my early Clojure code up for peer review from more experienced Clojure developers.

What I'm primarily looking to get out of this review:

- Call me out where I'm doing something Pythonic but not Lispy/Functional.
- Point me in the direction of useful Clojure core functions that I may just not know about.
- Guide me to use common Clojure developer conventions. How should I write doc comments? How should I name my variables?
- Tell me when something I've done just looks weird to an experienced Clojure developer.
- I'd really be interested in a lazy solution to my dfs algorithm that could produce all the possible solutions rather than just the first solution.

Okay here's the code.

[generic_search.clj](https://gitlab.com/willvaughn/classic-cs/-/blob/8a530f3eaa4464124e49289e5b8596917c8d93aa/cs-clj/src/cs_clj/ch2/generic_search.clj)

```clj
(ns cs-clj.ch2.generic-search)

(defn dfs
  [start is-goal? get-successors]
  (loop [frontier (list [start, []])
         explored #{start}]
    (let [[cur-loc cur-path] (peek frontier)
          next-path (conj cur-path cur-loc)]
      (cond
        (empty? frontier) nil
        (is-goal? cur-loc) next-path
        :else (let [successors (remove explored (get-successors cur-loc))
                    new-frontier (map (fn [loc] [loc next-path]) successors)
                    next-frontier (apply conj (pop frontier) new-frontier)
                    next-explored (apply conj explored successors)]
                (recur next-frontier next-explored))))))
```

[maze.clj](https://gitlab.com/willvaughn/classic-cs/-/blob/8a530f3eaa4464124e49289e5b8596917c8d93aa/cs-clj/src/cs_clj/ch2/maze.clj)

```clj
(ns cs-clj.ch2.maze
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]
            [cs-clj.ch2.generic-search :refer [dfs]]))

;; TODO: Seems like a fine way to represent an Enum, but...is there a better way?
(def cells {:empty " "
            :blocked "X"
            :start "S"
            :goal "G"
            :path "*"})

(defn random-cell-value
  [sparsity]
  (if (< (rand) sparsity)
    (:blocked cells)
    (:empty cells)))

(defn create-2d-grid
  [x y val-fn]
  ;; TODO: Is this idiomatic clojure? I'm trying to express a way to take either a
  ;; function or a value, and if it's a value wrap it in a function? Am I missing
  ;; the use of `identity` here in some way? Or perhaps an opportunity to use spec?
  ;; If spec, how?
  (let [val-fn (if (fn? val-fn) val-fn (fn [] val-fn))]
    ;; TODO: Wanted to represent grid as vectors, hence the `mapv`. With my use
    ;; of `assoc-in` to set values in the grid later I'm not certain it would have
    ;; worked with normal `map` returning sequences.
    (mapv (fn [_]
            (mapv (fn [_] (val-fn)) (range x)))
          (range y))))

(defn mark-grid-with
  [grid coord-vals]
  (reduce (fn [res-grid [coord val]]
            (assoc-in res-grid coord val))
          grid
          coord-vals))

;; TODO: use spec to validate that the start/goal are inbounds of rows and cols
;; TODO: think about whether maze "objects" could be a record.
;; TODO: Is there a good Protocol opportunity here?
;; mark-path, is-in-bounds?, is-blocked?, display-maze, get-successors, and mark-path
(defn create-maze
  "Creates randomly generated maze map."
  [& {:keys [rows cols sparsity start provided-goal]
      :or {rows 10
           cols 10
           sparsity 0.2
           start {:row 0 :col 0}
           provided-goal nil}}]
  (let [goal (if (nil? provided-goal)
               {:row (dec rows) :col (dec cols)}
               provided-goal)
        val-fn (partial random-cell-value sparsity)
        rand-grid (create-2d-grid rows cols val-fn)
        grid (mark-grid-with rand-grid [[[(:row start) (:col start)] (:start cells)]
                                        [[(:row goal) (:col goal)] (:goal cells)]])]
    {:rows rows
     :start start
     :goal goal
     :cols cols
     :grid grid}))

(defn is-in-bounds?
  "Checks if a location is inside the bounds of the maze."
  [maze loc]
  (let [{:keys [rows cols]} maze
        {:keys [row col]} loc]
    (and (<= 0 row)
         (< row rows)
         (<= 0 col)
         (< col cols))))

;; TODO Is it okay to use `backticks` in comments and doc strings to refer to
;; code vars and such? Is there a clojure docstrings and comments standard I should
;; know about? Like what if I wanted to autogen some API docs to a static site? Is
;; there a standard or at least popular tool like python's sphinx and restructured text?
(defn is-blocked?
  "Is the location at `loc` occupied in the `maze` by a wall character?"
  [maze loc]
  (let [grid (:grid maze)
        {:keys [row col]} loc
        cell-value (get-in grid [row col])]
    (= cell-value (:blocked cells))))

;; TODO: How do I get a doc comment on this function?
(def is-open? (complement is-blocked?))

(defn display-maze
  "Formats the maze grid to a legible string value."
  [{:keys [grid]}]
  (->> grid
       ;; TODO: Use (map #(string/join "" %)) here or is that too terse?
       ;; I feel like maybe the var name "row" helps clarity slightly.
       (map (fn [row] (string/join "" row)))
       (string/join "\n")))

(defn get-successors
  "Gets sequence of valid moves from the given location in the maze."
  [maze loc]
  (let [{:keys [rows cols]} maze
        {:keys [row col]} loc
        candidates [{:row (inc row) :col col}
                    {:row (dec row) :col col}
                    {:row row :col (inc col)}
                    {:row row :col (dec col)}]]
    (->> candidates
         (filter (partial is-in-bounds? maze))
         (filter (partial is-open? maze)))))

(defn mark-path
  "Mark the path through the maze with * characters. Returns altered maze."
  [maze path]
  ;; TODO: Is this call to subvec an idiomatic clojure way to slice a vector?
  ;; I'm trying to do here what I would do in python as `path_locs = path[1:-1]`
  (let [path-locs (subvec path 1 (dec (count path)))
        cell-val (:path cells)
        coord-vals (map (fn [{x :row y :col}]
                          [[x y] cell-val])
                        path-locs)]
    (assoc maze
           :grid (mark-grid-with (:grid maze) coord-vals))))

(defn -main []
  (let [maze (create-maze)
        is-goal? (partial = (:goal maze))
        get-suc (partial get-successors maze)
        path (dfs (:start maze) is-goal? get-suc)]
    (if (nil? path)
      (do
        (println (display-maze maze))
        (println "Could not solve."))
      (println (display-maze (mark-path maze path))))))
```

Produces output like this when run:

```
S******X
  X   ****
 X       *
X*********
**  X X
* XXX XX
****X    X
   *X X
   *******
      X  G
```

Also, here is the python [maze.py](https://gitlab.com/willvaughn/classic-cs/-/blob/8a530f3eaa4464124e49289e5b8596917c8d93aa/cs-py/ch2/maze.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial comments for only the `dfs` function:

#### Variable names

- `start` makes sense for the initial point.
- `is-goal?` `is-` is not necessary, the question marks already indicates that it's a predicate function, so name it `goal?`.
- `get-successors` is a pure function that will return the same answer given the same point, pure functions don't need a verb. Verbs are to indicate side effects. `successors` is fine.

For later two points I followed Stuart Sierra's [How to Name Clojure Functions](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/01/09/how-to-name-clojure-functions).

I would skip the intermediate variables names like `new-frontier` and `next-frontier` since I think they are more confusing than just chaining the function calls in a thread-last, it is implied in a `recur` that they will be the next. And in same fashion I think the `cur-` prefix is redundant since it is clear they belong to the current round in the recursion.

#### Data representation

I noticed points are represented as `{:row x, :col y}`, I would see if you can use `[x y]` and refactor to a `map` or even [`priority-map`](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map) with points as keys and values the paths (you could then sort by for example shorter length of path being higher priority).

Also (bit outside `dfs`) I would try to skip the `cells` map and only use it for printing because the conversions (e.g., `cell-val (:path cells)`) clutter up the code. I would use the `:empty`, `:blocked` and so on directly.

The use of the set as a function to find the new successors in `(remove explored (get-successors cur-loc))` is idiomatic.

#### nil-punning instead of `empty?` check

[`nil-punning`](https://lispcast.com/nil-punning/) is the use of `(when (seq coll) ..)` instead of `(if (empty? coll) nil ..)`. When calling `seq` on an empty coll it will return `nil`, and `nil` is falsy, and the falsy clause of `when` is `nil`. So that leads to the same behaviour as returning `nil` when the coll is empty.

Destructuring an empty value like you do in `[cur-loc cur-path] (peek frontier)` will also lead to two nils for `cur-loc` and `cur-path` and an `nil` for the overall vector, so you could achieve `nil-punning` using `(when-let [[cur-loc cur-path] (peek frontier)] ..)`, now if the frontier is empty you will return the false clause and thus `nil`.

#### New code with the above points addressed

```
(defn dfs
  [start goal? successors]
  (loop [frontier (list [start, []])
         explored #{start}]
    (when-let [[loc path] (peek frontier)]
      (let [next-path (conj path loc)]
        (if (goal? loc)
          next-path
          (recur (->> (successors loc)
                      (remove explored)
                      (map (fn [l] [l next-path]))
                      (apply conj (pop frontier)))
                 (apply conj explored (successors loc))))))))
```

#### Final remarks

Overall, if I spend more time on this I would start looking at the representation of the maze and how to walk over it with `bfs`. I'd try to find a shorter representation of the point and also the maze, starting with trying to encode a point as `[x y]`. Then the associative destructuring later on can be changed to sequential (e.g., `(let [[x y]] loc] ...)` instead of `(let [{:keys [row col]} loc] ...)`) and I think the code will become more concise and readable.

Hope this helps!

PS For the nested `mapv` I would try to use a [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) comprehension. Note:

```
(mapcat (fn [x]
          (mapv (fn [y] [x y]) (range 4 6)))
        (range 3))
;; => ([0 4] [0 5] [1 4] [1 5] [2 4] [2 5])

(for [x (range 3)
      y (range 4 6)]
  [x y])
;; => ([0 4] [0 5] [1 4] [1 5] [2 4] [2 5])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful response! This is incredibly helpful to me and  I greatly appreciate you taking the time to look through this. Soon I'm going to have a go at incorporating your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again! I got around to applying yours and others feedback. Here is a diff of them. https://gitlab.com/willvaughn/classic-cs/-/merge_requests/1

Comment: A couple of tweaks :
1. You evaluate `(successors loc)` twice. Extract it to a `let` binding. 
2. Replace the two instances of `(reduce conj ...)` with `(into ...)`.